# How to access your email account from Microsoft Office 365

Tags: email, office-365, microsoft-account

I have logged into the Microsoft Office home page and the screen looks like this:

[image]

**How** to proceed to view new email coming to my university account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on **Outlook** icon from Apps section (first icon in your screenshot). It will open in a new tab on your browser where you can see all your mails (inbox, draft, sent items, deleted items etc.).